# Movies Where Reality Changes at Night and People Wake Up to a Different World Every Day

Tags: movie, parallel-universe

I am looking to identify a movie where the world is changed every night and people wake up in a different world.  The only scene I can remember is of a City (vaguely 'Gotham' in muted colors) being torn down and then rebuilt while people sleep.  IIRC the people are unaware that this is happening.  English language, probably late eighties early nineties.

Also I dimly believe that this movie reminded me of another one with a similar plot line, so there may be two different movies that answer this question.

N.B. I am not thinking of "The Truman Show" or "The Langoliers".

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like [*Dark City*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118929/):

> John Murdoch awakens alone in a strange hotel to find that he has lost
> his memory and is wanted for a series of brutal and bizarre murders.
> While trying to piece together his past, he stumbles upon a fiendish
> underworld controlled by a group of beings known as The Strangers who
> possess the ability to put people to sleep ***and alter the city***
> and its inhabitants.

It's a 1998 film and, yes, the city is in muted (let's just say "Dark") colors.  I believe this clip shows the city changing:

[image: Dark City clip]

Comment: OK that's it, thanks very much.

Comment: @Interocitor please accept the answer as correct with the checkmark.